# How to prevent/unbind previous $watch in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using `$watch` in dynamic way so on every call its creating another `$watch` while I want to unbind previous `$watch`.

```
$scope.pagination =function(){
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function (newValue,oldValue) {      
    $scope.contestList = response; //getting response form $http
  }
}
```

I have multiple tabs. When a tab is clicked, the pagination function gets called:

```
$scope.ToggleTab = function(){
    $scope.pagination();
}
```

so its creating multiple `$watch` and every time I click on tab it creates another one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before adding a new watch you need to check if the watcher exists already or not. If it's already there you could just call `watcher()` this will remove the watcher from `$scope.$$watchers` array. And then register your watch. This will ensure your watch has been created only once.

```
var paginationWatch;
$scope.pagination = function() {
    if (paginationWatch) //check for watch exists
        paginationWatch(); //this line will destruct watch if its already there
    paginationWatch = $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            //getting response form $http`
            $scope.contestList = response;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a good practice to name the function returned by `$watch` a `deregisterer`, because it is a function that does the cleanup when you no longer want to watch --- it's definitely not a watcher