# AngularJS $watch unbind function is not defined when being called only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I am building a user session activity timer using AngularJS 1.6. I am using $scope.$watch to monitor the value of a countdown timer. This works for the most part although $watch is binding to the variable multiple times, every time the session timer function is called. To solve this, I think I need to simply unbind the watcher if it is already defined.

I saw some very simple examples on how to do this on SO, however nothing seems to be working. The $scope.$watch method returns a function that when called, unbinds the watcher.

However, anytime the unbind function is called, there is an error in the console.log 'ReferenceError: sessionWatchUnbind is not defined'. This seems very strange because the undefined error is happening within an IF statement that checks if the function is defined before calling it. How could it be defined and then undefined immediately after?

```
// If session countdown watch is already set unbind it to prevent multiple watches on the same value
if (sessionWatchUnbind) {
  console.log('sessionWatchUnbind ', sessionWatchUnbind); // This prints the function definition to the console log properly
  sessionWatchUnbind(); // This line throws an error 'ReferenceError: sessionWatchUnbind is not defined' but it was defined in the previous lines!?
}

// Set a watcher on session countdown value
sessionWatchUnbind = $scope.$watch('session_countdown', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {

    // continued...
  }
});
```

Also, the same error happens if I try placing the call inside the body of the watcher as such.

```
// Set a watcher on session countdown value
sessionWatchUnbind = $scope.$watch('session_countdown', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    sessionWatchUnbind(); // This line throws an error ReferenceError: sessionWatchUnbind is not defined
    // continued...
  }
});
```

I am pretty sure my code is following the numerous examples on how to do this. Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction!

UPDATE:
I got this to work by binding sessionWatchUnbind to 'this'. Perhaps because the outer wrapper function is bound to 'this' as well. This solution was based on the accepted answer here: [How to prevent/unbind previous $watch in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189361/how-to-prevent-unbind-previous-watch-in-angularjs)

```
    vm = this;

    vm.startActivity = function () {

    // If session countdown watch is already set unbind it to prevent multiple watches on the same value
    if (vm.sessionWatchUnbind) {
      vm.sessionWatchUnbind();
    }

    // Set a watcher on session countdown value
    vm.sessionWatchUnbind = $scope.$watch('session_countdown', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log('sessionWatchUnbind newValue, oldValue ', newValue, oldValue);
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          //continued...
      }
    });
```

Comment: `if (vm.sessionWatchUnbind) {
      vm.sessionWatchUnbind();
    }` this code will never work.

Comment: It's like *Function Expression*. We want to call the function when this function declared below.

Comment: I think it does because startActivity is called multiple times. If there is already a watcher on the session_countdown variable, then vm.sessionWatchUnbind will be defined. I got this structure from the accepted answer here. I definitely appreciate your help but not sure why you downvoted my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189361/how-to-prevent-unbind-previous-watch-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

This code works well for me:

```
const watcher = $scope.$watch('variable', value => {     
    // Remove watcher
    if (value)
       watcher();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for testing. I changed it slightly to use const sessionWatchUnbind = $scope.$watch(). It now seems to work inside the body of the unbind function now, but not outside of it. I need to unbind it if it is already defined so it needs to be called before the watcher is set.

Comment: @pengz if you will try to unbind it in your way (outside the function body) it will not work. Why? -Because after page refresh sessionWatchUnbind will always be undefined (you create the variable without its assignment, before watcher is set).

Comment: You can even try to do it, but declare the variable as `let sessionWatchUnbind`, not `const`

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some ideas that lead me to figure out the issue. I updated my question with the answer.

Comment: "it will not work. Why? -Because after page refresh sessionWatchUnbind will always be undefined" It gets called multiple times *before* a page refresh so it does work.